# i am not able to put this inside loop to shorten my code. It giver error of node type

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am trying to add this code in for-loop but it is giving me below error

> "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type
>   'Node'"

```
let tableBody = document.querySelector('#table tbody');    

let row1 = document.createElement('tr');
let row2 = row1.cloneNode(true);
let row3 = row1.cloneNode(true);
let row4 = row1.cloneNode(true);
let row5 = row1.cloneNode(true);

tableBody.appendChild(row1);
tableBody.appendChild(row2);
tableBody.appendChild(row3);
tableBody.appendChild(row4);
tableBody.appendChild(row5);
```

I am trying like this

```
for(i = 1; i <=5; i++){
  tableBody.appendChild('row' + i);
}
```

Comment: because you are trying to append the string 'row1', 'row2' and not the row1, row2, etc node itself.

Comment: You can create an array and push each new node to an array and then you can run for loop directly on the array. eg:  const arr = []; arr.push(row1.cloneNode(true))

Comment: Why not `tableBody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));` or `tableBody.appendChild(row1.cloneNode(true));` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending the actual object. You are appending a string.

Try it like that:

```
let tableBody = document.querySelector('#table tbody');    

let rows = []
rows.push(document.createElement('tr'));
rows.push(rows[0].cloneNode(true));
rows.push(rows[0].cloneNode(true));
rows.push(rows[0].cloneNode(true));
rows.push(rows[0].cloneNode(true));

rows.forEach(row => {
  tableBody.appendChild(row);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you code  `tableBody.appendChild('row' + i);` is not working `'row' + i` is nothing but a sting , which is not a variable holding a node,
put all the rows in array and add it from there

try this

```
let tableBody = document.querySelector('#table tbody');    

let rows=[];
rows.push(document.createElement('tr'));
rows.push(row1.cloneNode(true));
rows.push(row1.cloneNode(true));
rows.push(row1.cloneNode(true));
rows.push(row1.cloneNode(true));


for(i = 0 ; i <rows.length; i++){
  tableBody.appendChild(row[i]);
}
```

Suggesting reading : Array, variables, function

Answer (score 0):

appendChild takes DOM node object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), As mentioned by others you are providing a string.

It looks as though you want to create a table with 5 rows, if so, this is how you could go about it:

```
for(i = 1; i <=5; i++){
  tableBody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
}
```